# How Bhagavad Gita benefits us?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, gita

Hare Krishna

How Srimad Bhagavad Gita benefits us as described in Shastras, spiritually and in daily life?

I know some scriptural reference, but I want to know detailed references from Puranas, previous Acharya commentaries, reference from Gaudiya Sampradaya work, or related information with any research also welcome as well. Also if reference of Acharya Prabhupada related to benefits in any works very good.

Om Namah Shivaya
Jay Shri Krishna

Answer (score 7):

No need for any commentators. The answer is in the Gita itself. Krishna says in Chapter 18 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 68. He who, with supreme devotion to Me, teaches this deeply profound philosophy to those who are devoted to Me shall without question come to Me.
> 69. There is none among men who can do anything more pleasing to Me than he; nor shall there be another on earth dearer to Me than he.
> 70. And he who will study this sacred dialogue of ours--by him shall I have been worshipped through knowledge as a sacrifice; such is My judgement.
> 71. And the man who hears this, full of faith and free from malice--even he, liberated from sin, shall attain the happy regions of the righteous.
> 72. Has it been heard by you, O Partha, with an undivided mind? Has your delusion, born of ignorance, been destroyed, O Dhananjaya?

Answer (score 2):

Krishna himself tells the benefits.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06042.htm

> And he who will study this holy converse between us, by him will have been offered to Me the sacrifice of knowledge. Such is my opinion. Even the man who, with faith and without cavil, will hear it (read), even he freed (from re-birth), will obtain of the blessed regions of those that perform pious acts.